# Winforms treeview sort() causes nullreference exception

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, treeview

Have a classic Winforms application with a treeview.

The nodes in the treeview can be filtered using a checkbox (apply filter y/n).

The nodes removed by the filter are saved to a dictionary, so they can be restored if the filter checkbox is unchecked.

The restore of the nodes in the dictionary goes well. The nodes are restored correctly in the right locations.

Problem is that I can't sort the treeview after the nodes have been restored.

When I try to call treeview.Sort(), I get a nullreference exception.

I have tried overriding treeview.TreeViewNodeSorter(), but it looks like the exception isn't caused by the comparing of the nodes.

As far as I can see, the nullreference exception appears after the comparing have finished and Sort() is about to close up and exit.

Have any of you seen such behaviour before? - and can you share a trick to fix it?

---

The code (it's the tvData.Sort() calls that causes an exception):

```
foreach(TreeNode currentNode in removedTreeNodes.Keys)
{
    if (removedTreeNodes[currentNode] == null)
    {
         tvData.Nodes.Add(currentNode);
    }

    foreach(TreeNode creator in tvData.Nodes)
    {
        if(creator == removedTreeNodes[currentNode])
        {
             creator.Nodes.Add(currentNode);
        }
    }
}

removedTreeNodes = new Dictionary<TreeNode, TreeNode>();

if (tvData.SelectedNode != null)
{
    TreeNode selectedNode = tvData.SelectedNode;

    tvData.Sort();

    tvData.SelectedNode = tvData.FindNodeByTagId(selectedNode);
}
else
{
    tvData.Sort();
}
```

Comment: Find the instruction that is giving the error, or post the full Stack Trace.

Comment: SelectedNode is only a single item which you cannot sort.  I think you want selectedNode.Nodes which will sort the children of the node.

Comment: It's only possible to select a single node, but the tvData.Sort() also fails for tvData.SelectedData = null (i.e.where we don't worry about SelectedNode)

Comment: Yes.  It is similar to a List<> object.  If you have only one item in a list the sort will not fail.  The sort will fail in a List<> if the list is null.  A single selectedNode is not a collection (the child nodes are a collection) so the sort is failing because it is not a collection.

Comment: tvData is the treeview control. It contains 300+ nodes, so there is not only one item.